# How do I reference a specific issue comment on github?

Tags: github

I'm trying to refer to a specific issue comment on github, in my readme. But I can't find any information on how to do that ([here](https://github.com/blog/957-introducing-issue-mentions) for example). I know that it's possible to link to issues, but is it possible to link to specific comments in that issue?

Answer (score 351, accepted):

You can click on the date in the header of the comment to get a URL to the comment

[image]

For example, for issue https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/issues/5 one of the comments has the following link: https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/issues/5#issuecomment-51084491.

Comment: For those wanting to format their reference like so: #10359 (comment), note that GitHub will handle this formatting automatically if you just paste the link as-is - without wrapping it in [text](url) markdown :)

Comment: Also note that this works identically for comments on commits (not _just_ comments on issues).

Answer (score 15):

**Simple method:**

Every comment in github has header like below

```
[Commenter Name] commented on [x days ago]
```

Right click the date information i.e. [x days ago] and copy the link

Answer (score 7):

Since August 2018, there is a more intuitive (and likely more reliable) way.
See "[**Copy the URL of a comment**](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-08-17-copy-url-comment-action/)":

> Previously, in order to grab a permalink to a comment within an issue or pull request, you’d need to copy the URL from a comment’s timestamp.
>
> **Now you can click Copy URL within the comment’s options menu to quickly copy the URL to your clipboard.**

[image: Copy comment URL].

This works on commits in a Pull Request too:
https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37558#discussion_r211356672 refers to:

[image: Copy on PR comment]

---

And [since February 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-02-13-copy-comment-permalinks-on-mobile/), that works on mobile too!

> Issue and pull request comment permalinks can now be copied on mobile devices, via the comment action menu.

Comment: Would not call it simpler, as it is as simple as getting the link from the date - rather more intuitive and likely more reliable.

Comment: @Veverke I agree, and have edited the answer accordingly