# How do I reference a PR comment link in a commit message on Github

Tags: github

I have followed the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163598/how-do-i-reference-a-specific-issue-comment-on-github), but none worked.

If I need to make reference to a PR comment, say a change request, in my commit, how do I go about it? I have tried

```
git commit -m 'Effect the changes mentioned in https://github.com/team/repo/pull/1#issuecomment-897102875'
```

but on Github it shows the PR number := `Effect the changes mentioned in #1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation for "magic links" or [Autolinked references and URLs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/autolinked-references-and-urls) does mention pull request, but not pull request comments.

So a comment reference itself might not be supported at the moment.